# Skip first cycle of loop when 'Categories equals null

Tags: java, loops

I am reading data from json file, And i want to do a get items by categories

```
 public List<Item> getItemsByCategory(String category) {
        List<Item> matchingCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : books.getItems()) {
            List<String> categories1 = item.getVolumeInfo().getCategories();
            // categories1 == null for the first item  so the below for loop fails
            for (String cat : categories1) {
                if (cat.equals(category)) {
                    matchingCategory.add(item);
                } else throw new MyResourceNotFoundException(String.format("category with type %s is not found"));
            }
        }
        return matchingCategory;
    }
```

My first item in th json file has no category this is why categories is null in the first loop , How can i skip it and continue in the item in the json file , Instead of getting null pointer exception

I tried using break but it ends the loop without starting next one

This is my json im reading data from here.

```
{
  "requestedUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=java&maxResults=40",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "7tkN1CYzn2cC",
      "etag": "pfjjxSpetIM",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/7tkN1CYzn2cC",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "A Hypervista of the Java Landscape",
        "publisher": "InfoStrategist.com",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9781592432172"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "1592432174"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "1.0.1.0.preview.3",
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&pg=PP1&dq=java&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&dq=java&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape.html?hl=&id=7tkN1CYzn2cC"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.pl/books/download/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape-sample-epub.acsm?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.pl/books/download/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape-sample-pdf.acsm?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "-SYM4PW-YAgC",
      "etag": "dXytGSDckJk",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/-SYM4PW-YAgC",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "The Religion of Java",
        "authors": [
          "Clifford Geertz"
        ],
        "publisher": "University of Chicago Press",
        "publishedDate": "1976-02-15",
        "description": "Written with a rare combination of analysis and speculation, this comprehensive study of Javanese religion is one of the few books on the religion of a non-Western people which emphasizes variation and conflict in belief as well as similarity and harmony. The reader becomes aware of the intricacy and depth of Javanese spiritual life and the problems of political and social integration reflected in the religion. The Religion of Java will interest specialists in Southeast Asia, anthropologists and sociologists concerned with the social analysis of religious belief and ideology, students of comparative religion, and civil servants dealing with governmental policy toward Indonesia and Southeast Asia.",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "0226285103"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9780226285108"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "pageCount": 392,
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "categories": [
          "Religion"
        ],
        "averageRating": 4.0,
        "ratingsCount": 4,
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "2.1.2.0.preview.3",
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=java&hl=&cd=2&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&dq=java&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Religion_of_Java.html?hl=&id=-SYM4PW-YAgC"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.pl/books/download/The_Religion_of_Java-sample-epub.acsm?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": false
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=-SYM4PW-YAgC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      },
      "searchInfo": {
        "textSnippet": "Written with a rare combination of analysis and speculation, this comprehensive study of Javanese religion is one of the few books on the religion of a non-Western people which emphasizes variation and conflict in belief as well as ..."
      }
    } etc
```

As above the first item has no category but the second does so i should be able to get the second it

Comment: `if(catergories1 == null) continue;`?

Comment: I tried this and it returns empty, no error but also no items

Comment: @StaticBeagle are u there

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i have done , Using continue and break as well, But i had to remove my exception handler,

```
  public List<Item> getItemsByCategory(String category) {
        List<Item> matchingCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : books.getItems()) {
            List<String> categories1 = item.getVolumeInfo().getCategories();
            if(categories1 == null) continue;
            for (String cat : categories1) {
                if (cat.equals(category)) {
                    matchingCategory.add(item);
                } else break;   //throw new MyResourceNotFoundException(String.format("category with type %s is not found", category));
            }
        }
        return matchingCategory;
    }
```

How can i put back the throw new Exception

Comment: You had to remove the exception, because the usage was incorrectly implemented. The same applies to `break`. You obviously want to check _every_ value in `categories1` and not just the first one. This is also not an answer, but a second question. But you don't need to ask that question either, because I already told you the issue. The solution is quite easy.

Comment: @Tom please can you show me piece of code to help with the accurate solution

Answer (score 0):

Why can’t you add an condition..?

```
if(categories1 != null) {
    for() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns empty, no error but also no items